# How can I set the swagger documentation to use dd/MM/yyyy format?

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, swagger

I am parsing a date to a rest service using spring-boot and Swagger for documenting the api.

On the endpoint, I only want to have dates without hours. And is easily achieved with `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")`. Note that I prefer that days comes first than months.

The endpoint is working fine when using curl, then I do not think that is the issue about it. For example to set the 30 of November of current year, I can call it with Curl as follows:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8085/app/api/endpoint?creationTime=30%2F11%2F2020" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

And works fine. But if I use directly the Swagger page for testing I have these cases:

First, if I set date as 30/11/2020, swagger does not allow me to proceed:

[image]

If I set date as 11/30/2020, swagger allows me to continue, but I get this error:

```
"message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date] for value '11/30/2020'; nested exception is org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Cannot parse \"11/30/2020\": Value 30 for monthOfYear must be in the range [1,12]",
```

As I am telling that is the month number 30. And makes sense to me.

If I set 05/11/2020, Swagger allows me to send the request and the final date is the 5 of November, as is the format I have defined.

For me seems that swagger is filtering me by `MM/dd/yyyy` format and not using my `dd/MM/yyyy` that is really defined on the endpoint. Is there any option to set the swagger validation as `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Note: swagger version used `2.9.2`. Spring-boot version `2.1.8.RELEASE`

Answer (score 1):

We can use,
swagger ..

```
birthday:
    description: Date of birth
    type: date
    format: DD/MM/YYYY
    example: "30/11/2022"
```

For nestjs you can use

```
@ApiProperty({ example: "20-09-2022", type:Date,  default: 'DD/MM/YYYY', format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' })
```

Comment: Note that the question is related to Java with Spring, not node or other languages.

Comment: Sorry I didnot mentioned the java spring boot, In spring boot its related to Date type,
change Date to LocalDate data type , it will work fine

Example code here's 
@RequestHeader(required = false) LocalDate startDate,